# Changing selected index of combo box with databinding in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am trying to make the conversion from `Winforms` to `WPF` in c#. I am struggling a bit with `WVVM` and `data binding`. I admit I don't have a full grasp on the way everything works together but I think i just need more practice.

I used [this article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99330/WPF-Step-by-Step-Getting-Started-with-WPF-and-Expr?fid=1582119&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Expanded&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx) to help me understand how to convert my local address book application from WinForms to WPF.

While I can get data binding to work fine with int and string I am struggling with a ComboBox. The data is stored in an xml file and stored as strings and int's in the contacts class. The ComboBox should auto update when a location is selected from a list box. I have this all working for properties that allow user custom information. This particular setting needs to be a drop down for pre-set values.

How do I convert the string and pass the SelectedIndex[] property to the comboBox through data binding?

I omitted some of the extra working code used in string population for text boxes to clean it up some.

XAML

```
<Window
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:mainviewModel x:Name="viewModel1"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="#FF8B8686">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="174" Margin="44,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="244,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedContact.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="244,120,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedContact.Address}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxBandwidth" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="244,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedContact.Bandwidth}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Write Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,271,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact.Combo}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="3" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4" />
            </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Contact.cs

```
public class Contact : ViewModelEntity
{
    public Contact()
    {
    }

    protected int combo;
    public int Combo
    {
        get { return combo; }
        set
        {
            if (combo != value)
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case 1:
                        combo = ComboBox.SelectedIndex[0];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        combo = ComboBox.SelectedIndex[1];
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        combo = ComboBox.SelectedIndex[2];
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        combo = ComboBox.SelectedIndex[3];
                        break;
                    default:
                        combo = ComboBox.SelectedIndex[0];
                        break;
                }
                // combo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Combo");
            }
        }
    }
```

mainviewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.viewmodels
{
    public class mainviewModel:ViewModelEntity
    {

       public mainviewModel()
        { }
        protected Contact selectedContact = null;

        protected ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

        public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts
        {
            get { return contacts; }
            set { contacts = value; }
        }


        public Contact SelectedContact
        {
            get { return selectedContact; }
            set {
                if (selectedContact != value)
                {
                    selectedContact = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedContact");
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you directly bind it to the `SelectedIndex` directly?

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
              Width="120"
              Margin="267,229,0,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedContact.Combo}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4" />
    </ComboBox>
```

In code behind :

```
protected int combo;
public int Combo
{
    get { return combo; }
    set
    {
        combo = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Combo");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank you for pointing that out. I'm still trying to get used to thinking about controls this way. It never occurred to me to just move the binding to another property. I was approaching the situation like selelecteditem was the only property you can bind to, Which simply isn't the case!

Thank you very much for showing me my error and that i was far over complicating it.

Comment: Its ok. When you get used to working with wpf,  you will think like me only. Actually for every problem,  there are several solutions. We need to find out which one is the best and less time consuming. That's it.